# How can I make nuget download packges for publish?

Tags: nuget, .net-5

I have a project with the following packages

[image]

Not the packages where I drew the red line.

When I now run dotnet publish I get the following errors
[image]

It says some of the packages from first screen shot of visual studio is missing.
And sure enough, if I browse there they are missing.

If i run the project it works fine, clean, build, all works great. But still I get this error on publish.

How can I solve?

Comment: Any reason you're still using ADAL? While supported, you should really move to MSAL. The packages you're using are deprecated and there are far newer versions than the ones you're using. For example, your version of `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` is **over 2 years old**

Comment: That is part of dbup and is not my package. For now, all I need is to get them downloaded so I can do my build.

Comment: You **might** be able to get it to work by manually depending on the `System.Security.Cryptography` packages version 4.3.0 as the error messages tell you. I'd anyway suggest you to get rid of that `dbup`, it's insanely outdated and, as with all outdated packages, insecure.

Comment: This is mainly a nuget question. The package is available on nuget. Why doesn't it download the package for me? The version is available here https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/

Comment: While I am still curious to why it doesn't download packages and throws error. I solved it by running my publish as self-contained once, which seems to have downloaded the required files. Then I could publish again but without self-contained and now it worked.